# Terrible kerning of double f in subscript of Latex

Tags: pdftex, subscripts, kerning

I'm "remastering" my PhD thesis which is in the fatigue of composite materials. A common term is the effective stress intensity factor, which is $ \Delta K_{eff} $ in LaTeX code. Unfortunately, when typeset it looks like this:
[image]

I find the kerning between the two f characters in the subscript terrible. Can anyone suggest a fix for this. I've looked around this forum but nothing has popped out as a simple reliable solution. I am using a Mac (10.11) with MacTex 2015 and TexStudio as my editor/IDE.

Here's a MWE for those who need one:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}

        \Delta K_{eff}

    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It should be `\Delta K_{\textup{eff}}`; add also `\usepackage{amsmath}`

Comment: Alternatively, if it needs to be italic, `\Delta K_{\mathit{eff}}` will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
\makeatletter
\begingroup\lccode`\~=\_ \lowercase{\endgroup
  \def~}{\@ifnextchar|\sbtext\sb}
\def\sbtext|#1|{\sb{\textnormal{#1}}}
\makeatother
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\_=12 \mathcode`\_="8000 }
```

And use like always except that if the “argument” of `_` is between `|..|` then it will be typeset upright.

```
A_{i} + B_{i+1} = K_|eff|
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems I need to learn more about the typesetting of maths. I was unaware that subscripts should be Roman script. So changing my code to read $ \Deltak_\mathrm{eff} $ fixes the problem. Note that if I use \mathit instead of \mathrm I get properly kerning of the ff pair in an italic style. The answers and comments of several of your made this apparent to me. Thanks for your quick help.

Comment: There is a big difference here, "eff" is not an index variable, it is a name, and thus should be typeset differently doing order to distinguish it from index variables, thus the upright recommendation